# Como traer la información de la base de dados por el id

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> "Hola tengo este código para recuperar la información de la base de
> datos, tengo un List que me trae todos los datos pero como debería ser
> el código para traer solo 1 columna por id?
>
> ```
> Este es el método que me recupera todas las columnas, mi duda es como seria el codigo para recuperar por id."
> ```

```
package data;

import domain.PersonaDTO;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PersonaDaoJDBC implements PersonaDao{
    
    private static final String SQL_SELECT="SELECT * FROM persona";
    private static final String SQL_SELECT_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE idPersona=?";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT="INSERT INTO persona (dni,nombre,fecha,email,direccion,telefono) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE="UPDATE persona SET dni=?,nombre=?,fecha=?,email=?,direccion=?,telefono=? WHERE idPersona=?";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE="DELETE FROM persona WHERE idPersona=?";

    @Override
    public List<PersonaDTO> select(){
     
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PersonaDTO persona = null;
            List<PersonaDTO>personas = new ArrayList<>();
        
         try {
            conn = Conexion.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                int idPersona = rs.getInt("idPersona");
                String dni = rs.getString("dni");
                String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                String fecha = rs.getString("fecha");
                String direccion = rs.getString("direccion");
                String telefono = rs.getString("telefono");
                
                persona = new PersonaDTO(idPersona, dni, nombre, fecha, direccion, telefono);
                personas.add(persona);
             }
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }finally{
              Conexion.close(rs);
            Conexion.close(stmt);
            Conexion.close(conn);
         }
        
         return personas;
    }

Pensaba que podría ser tal vez así

@Override
    public void recuperar(PersonaDTO persona) throws SQLException {
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
        
         try {
            conn = Conexion.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID);
            stmt.setInt(1,persona.getIdPersona());
            rs.absolute(1);
            
            int idPersona = rs.getInt("idPersona");
            String dni = rs.getString("dni");
            String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
            String fecha = rs.getString("fecha");
            String direccion = rs.getString("direccion");
            String telefono = rs.getString("telefono");
           
            persona.setDni(dni);
            persona.setNombre(nombre);
            persona.setFecha(fecha);
            persona.setDireccion(direccion);
            persona.setTelefono(telefono);
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }finally{
             Conexion.close(rs);
            Conexion.close(stmt);
            Conexion.close(conn);
         }
        
    }
```

> Y si de esta manera es valida, como puedo imprimir el valor de esa
> columna atreves del main?
> Desde el main tengo una lista que me trae todos los datos y con un metodo static que recibe una lista mando a imprimir todos los datos,
> he intentado hacer algo parecido para traer solo 1 registro y aun no
> he encontrado alguna manera de hacerlo

Comment: El cuerpo de tu método `recuperar` está bien. Pero si quieres retornar el objeto `Persona` debes declararlo del tipo `Persona`  y hacer un return del objeto una vez llenado con los resultados de la consulta. Lo extraño es que obtienes el id del objeto para pasarlo como parámetro de la consulta, ¿acaso el objeto no tiene ya las otras propiedades? ¿por qué necesitarías llenarlo de nuevo en ese caso?

Comment: Si ósea, esa es mi duda. puedo recuperar los datos directamente solo con el id como los mencionas, ya que este id ya me recupera los datos y no necesitaría volverlos a pedir, he ahí mi duda, ya con el id, como podría imprimir los datos tomando solo el id

Comment: Lo que preguntas no se entiende. El objeto `Persona` podría tener un método `toString()` que te imprima todos los datos de la persona, no sé si es eso lo que buscas.